# Request time out in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests, urllib3

I am trying to send a request to the Louis Vuitton, but none of the the libraries that I have used are able to get a response. Even though i can access the site fine from the browser. Is there something im doing wrong?

I have used *requests*,*urllib3* and *BeautifulSoup* and none of my trials with these libraries have been successful.

Code:

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup


url = 'https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/products/pocket-organizer-monogram-other-nvprod2380073v'
req = Request(url , headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/84.0.4147.105'})

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
title = page_soup.find("title")
print(title)
```

Output:
Doesn't give me one, just stays blank until I KeyboardInterrupt.

Notes:
The purpose of this project will be to monitor the website to detect if any changes occur. (Wallet goes back in stock)

Comment: Where do is it hang? Is it after making the request or while creating the soup?

Comment: it hangs in line `webpage = urlopen(req).read()`

Comment: I can reproduce this using the code you provided

I think the problem is something to do with the headers. For me, adding these headers makes the script work:

`req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64)'})`

alternatively, using your headers in `requests` (`import requests`) seems to work (gives a 200 status with a body that should be parsable by bs4)

e.g. `requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Chrome/84.0.4147.105'})`

Do any of those work for you?

Comment: @honk I saw your'e comment after posting my answer. You are correct, changing the `headers` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're `headers` are incorrect.

```
from urllib.request import Request, urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

HEADERS = {
'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)'
}

url = 'https://us.louisvuitton.com/eng-us/products/pocket-organizer-monogram-other-nvprod2380073v'
req = Request(url, headers=HEADERS)

webpage = urlopen(req).read()
page_soup = soup(webpage, "html.parser")
title = page_soup.find("title")
print(title.text)
```

Outputs:

```
Pocket Organizer Monogram Other in Blue - Small Leather Goods M69679 | LOUIS VUITTON ®
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I would've never thought it was going to be the headers.